# Display combination of Phonetic Characters on a ggplot graph using a different computer font

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating graphic plots that contain IPA symbols (Phonetic symbols) using ggplot on R. The font used by ggplot looks great for most of the characters, but when it's a combination of characters, they look  misaligned when displayed in the output. A combination of characters is something like this: t̪ (t + U032A) or ʈ͡ʂ (U0288+U0282+U0361).

This is the data.frame and code I used for the graph:

```
phones <- c("a", "e", "k", "ə", "ʈ͡ʂ", "n", "t͡ʃ", "n̪", "s", "l̪", "t̪")
freq   <- c(34,   28, 29,  26,    10,   8,     5,   3,   2,   4,   1)
df     <- data.frame(phones, freq)

  library(ggplot2)

    graph <- ggplot(subset(df, freq > 0), aes(x = reorder(phones, -freq), y = freq)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
    graph

    png(
      filename = "test.png",
      height   = 1500,  width    = 2500,
      res      = 300,   units    = "px")
    graph +     labs(title = "", 
                 subtitle="", 
                 caption  = "",
                 x = "",
                 y = "")
    dev.off(which = dev.cur())
```

This creates the following graph:
[image: Graph of frequency of some phones]

And I'm expecting something like this (characters in red using a special font Doulos SIL):
[image: Graph with frequency of some phones, and expected font display]

I think that I can specify the computer font Doulos SIL ([Link to font](https://software.sil.org/doulos/download/)) (or any other font that display combination of characters) before creating the graph in order to display neat characters, but I haven't been able to do so on my code. I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You can specify the font of ggplot elements via customized themes ( https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/07/using-different-fonts-with-ggplot2/ ), unless Doulos SIL as such is not properly rendered or printed by your system.

Comment: That answers my question, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72352717/display-combination-of-phonetic-characters-on-a-ggplot-graph-using-a-different-c#comment127824380_72352717), the solution for this answer is to indicate the font within the function theme() with a text option, for example:

```
graph <- ggplot(subset(df, freq > 0), aes(x = reorder(phones, -freq), y = freq)) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
 theme(text=element_text(family = "TT Doulos SIL"))
```